# Start getMapAsync after another async task completes

Tags: android, json, google-maps, asynchronous

So this is some of my code

```
JSONTask a=new JSONTask();
a.execute("https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path="+mypath+"&interpolate=true&key=AIzaSyANi8h64Kns-eZObim4oSFGrx6Fyc2dDxU");
MapFragment mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
mMap.getMapAsync(this);
```

It takes some locations through JSONTask(it's also an async task).My problem is that the map Async gets executed before i can get the data from JSON into an array.How can I make it so that the map Async waits for the JSON async to be finished before it starts?

I have tried moving the map async call into the onPostExecute of JSON as a try for a quick fix but that just gives me an error.One way might be to wait until "JSONTask a" getStatus() returns AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED but I have no idea how to.I tried with a empty while that waits until getStatus==finished but that just results in the map call never executing

Comment: What is error that it gives when you implement onPostExecute() ?

Comment: Please share the error which you got when you moved getMapAsync method to onPostExecute of JSONTask

Comment: getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback) in MapFragment cannot be applied to (com.example.selami.mapshow.Main2Activity.JSONTask)